# How to expand trigonometric equation into non quadratic terms in MAPLE

Tags: trigonometry, maple

I'm working with partial differential equations at the moment and at a point I get a trigonometric equation like this:

> $$\sin^{2}(\pi x)\cos(2 \pi x)$$

Now I would like to know how I can expand this in maple into non quadratic terms (this will be useful because I can see the fourierterms by sight then instead of doing a big inverse fourier transformation)

The answer here would be:

> $$-1/4-(1/4)\cdot \cos(4\pi x)+(1/2)\cdot\cos(2 \pi x)$$

I can do this by hand but I'd like to be able to do it with maple to save time. 
I should be possible since in my notes I see that the result was done by maple (M! above the equal sign ^^)

I tried simplify(...,trig) and expand.. But those didn't help.

Comment: how about combine(...,trig)?

Comment: @Maesumi thanks!! That worked! ^^ can't you post it in an answer so I can give you a correct answer reward?

Comment: Maesumi's works great.  Another more pedestrian one is:  convert(%,exp);expand(%);simplify(%,symbolic);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about starting with `combine(...,trig)`? There are just too many ways of writing a trig expression and it is a bit hard to tell a computer algebra system like Maple to "do it this way"! [Here are some more examples.](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=simplify%2ftrig)

Comment: Well to be honest, I know it's hard to tell it 'do it this way', but what I asked to expand it into none quadratic terms is exactly what combine(...,trig) seems to do (also looking at the other examples), so for what I asked, it actually seems to be possible to tell maple 'Do this pretty please' :D